# why id is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the id of the doc but I got undefine when i console.log
is there a way to also include the doc id ?

```
    this.unsubscribe = FirestoreService.getMessagesSnapshot(selected.id, selected.userId).onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        if(querySnapshot.size > 0) {
            let tempObject = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
               
                tempObject.push({
                    **id:doc.id,**
                    chatId: doc.data().chatId,
                    membersId: doc.data().membersId,
                    name: selected.name,
                    picRatio: doc.data().picRatio,
                    picUrl: doc.data().picUrl,
                    fileUrl: doc.data().fileUrl,
                    senderId: doc.data().senderId,
                    text: doc.data().text,
                    thumbUrl: doc.data().thumbUrl,
                    time: doc.data().time.toDate(),
                    videoUrl: doc.data().videoUrl,
                });
            });
```

Comment: Are you saying `doc.id` is undefined? If so, what does `doc` look like? Is it an object with an `id` property?

Comment: Please include the source for `FirestoreService.getMessagesSnapshot()`.

Comment: I want to get the document name and the doc.id outputs array of name document names if i console log it below this "querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {" but  inside this code " tempObject.push({" doc.id dont work

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "**It doesn't work**". Can you show us **value** of `console.log(querySnapshot)`? A snapshot or copy-paste of that log?

Comment: I gree with @AjeetShah we need to know what is inside the querySnapshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah that's the old me , and I'm really dumb
I've been expecting to have an array of object but the output of the snapchat here is only an object.

specific query using doc id throws an object where else a where clause gives a array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).